# Regexp (query) for email gives syntax error when sing @

Tags: jquery, regex, email-validation

I'm using this simple regexp to validate an email in query, but it gives a syntax error because of the '@'.

```
var regexEmail = '^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$';
```

Is there a work around for this problem?

**EDIT**

Like I said, its the use of the character '@' that causes the problem. When delete it from te expression, the syntax error disappears. Maybe it's because I'm using it in a CSHTML page, whenever I type in the '@', it turns yellow.

Comment: What syntax error does it output?

Comment: you don't need to give `\b` at the start or at the end.

Comment: It shows this output error: "[" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

Comment: Seems to work okay here: http://jsfiddle.net/1bL9pgoc/ What's the rest of your code?

Comment: I'm using it on a CSHTML page, maybe that got something to do with it

Comment: Is the error in the javascript console or shown in the browser content window? If it's in the browser window definitely something else. Sounds like the server is trying to evaluate the code as something else.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/bJ6rZ5/2  Only input strings of these type are accepted.Are you sure your are not giving small alphabets in your mail id?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

var pattern=\"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$\";